# Importing a QT project into visual studio 2019 gives me lots of LNK2001 errors

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, visual-studio-2019, glfw

I'm trying to build both an openGL script and a QT window at the same time. I thought simply importing the QT project into visual studio using the official plugin would suffice but things are never that easy with c++. I have already linked all my libraries and includes inside the project settings, including the stuff inside the msvc2019_64 folder, glfw, glad and QtWidgets.

main file, called shader_class.cpp

```
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include "shader.h"
#include <iostream>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include "login.h"

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height);
void processInput(GLFWwindow* window);

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    // initialize GLFW
    glfwInit();
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    #ifdef __APPLE__
        glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FOWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);
    #endif

    // creating the glfw window
        GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "aprende opengl", NULL, NULL);
        
        // if the window does not initialize
        if (window == NULL) {
            std::cout << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
            glfwTerminate();
            return -1;
        }
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        glfwSetFramebufferSizeCallback(window, framebuffer_size_callback);

        // glad: load all openGL pointers
        if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
            std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
            return -1;
        }

        //builds the shader with our header file
        // you can name your shader files however you like
        shader ourShader("3.3.shader.vs", "3.3.shader.fs");

        // set up vertex data (and buffer(s)) and configure vertex attributes
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        float vertices[] = {
            // positions         // colors
             0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom right
            -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  // bottom left
             0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f   // top 
        };

        unsigned int VBO, VAO;
        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);

        // bind the Vertex Array Object first, then bind and set vertex
        // buffer(s), and then configure vertex attributes(s).
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        // position attributes
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // color attributes
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 6 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

        // You can unbind the VAO afterwards so other VAO calls won't accidentally 
        // modify this VAO, but this rarely happens. Modifying other VAOs 
        // requires a call to glBindVertexArray anyways so we generally 
        // don't unbind VAOs (nor VBOs) when it's not directly necessary.
        // glBindVertexArray(0);

        // render loop
        while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
            // input
            processInput(window);

            // render
            glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

            // renderiza el triangulo
            ourShader.use();
            glBindVertexArray(VAO);
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

            // GLFW: swap buffers and poll IO events (mouse pressed, etc)
            glfwSwapBuffers(window);
            glfwPollEvents();
        }

        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
        // glfw: terminate, clearing all previously allocated GLFW resources.
        // ------------------------------------------------------------------
        glfwTerminate();

        // QT constructor stuff
        QApplication a(argc, argv);
        login w;
        w.show();
        return a.exec();

}

void processInput(GLFWwindow* window) {
    if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) == GLFW_PRESS) {
        glfwSetWindowShouldClose(window, true);
    }
}

void framebuffer_size_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int width, int height) {
    // make sure the viewport matches the new window dimensions; note that width and 
    // height will be significantly larger than specified on retina displays.
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

the header of this main file, called shader.h

```
#pragma once
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

#include <glad/glad.h>

#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

class shader {
    public:
        unsigned int ID;
        // this constructor builds the shader rather quickly
        shader(const char* vertexPath, const char* fragmentPath) {
            // 1.- obtain the vertex/fragment code from filepath
            std::string vertexCode;
            std::string fragmentCode;
            std::ifstream vShaderFile;
            std::ifstream fShaderFile;

            // makes sure the ifstream objects can throw exceptions
            vShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
            fShaderFile.exceptions(std::ifstream::failbit | std::ifstream::badbit);
            try {
                vShaderFile.open(vertexPath);
                fShaderFile.open(fragmentPath);
                std::stringstream vShaderStream, fShaderStream;

                // reads the archive buffers and converts them to string
                vShaderStream << vShaderFile.rdbuf();
                fShaderStream << fShaderFile.rdbuf();

                // close these file handlers
                vShaderFile.close();
                fShaderFile.close();

                // convert stream objects to string
                vertexCode = vShaderStream.str();
                fragmentCode = fShaderStream.str();
            }// end of try
            catch (std::ifstream::failure& e) {
                std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FILE_NOT_SUCCESFULLY_READ" << std::endl;
            }// end of catch

            const char* vShaderCode = vertexCode.c_str();
            const char* fShaderCode = fragmentCode.c_str();

            // 2.- compiles the shader objects
            unsigned int vertex, fragment;
            // vertex shader
            vertex = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(vertex, 1, &vShaderCode, NULL);
            glCompileShader(vertex);
            
            checkCompileErrors(vertex, "VERTEX");

            // fragment shader
            fragment = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
            glShaderSource(fragment, 1, &fShaderCode, NULL);
            glCompileShader(fragment);
            checkCompileErrors(fragment, "FRAGMENT");

            // shader program
            ID = glCreateProgram();
            glAttachShader(ID, vertex);
            glAttachShader(ID, fragment);
            glLinkProgram(ID);
            checkCompileErrors(ID, "PROGRAM");

            // since the shaders have been linked to the program, they're no longer needed
            glDeleteShader(vertex);
            glDeleteShader(fragment);
        }// end of constructor

        // turn on the shader
        void use() {
            glUseProgram(ID);
        }

        // utility uniform functions
        void setBool(const std::string& name, bool value) const {
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), (int)value);
        }

        void setInt(const std::string& name, int value) const {
            glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
        }

        void setFloat(const std::string& name, float value) const {
            glUniform1f(glGetUniformLocation(ID, name.c_str()), value);
        }
    
    private:
        // checks for compile errors or linking errors
        void checkCompileErrors(unsigned int shader, std::string type) {
            int success;
            char infoLog[1024];
            if (type != "PROGRAM") {
                glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
                if (!success) {
                    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
                    if (!success) {
                        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER_COMPILATION_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    glGetProgramiv(shader, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
                    if (!success) {
                        glGetProgramInfoLog(shader, 1024, NULL, infoLog);
                        std::cout << "ERROR::PROGRAM_LINKING_ERROR of type: " << type << "\n" << infoLog << "\n -- --------------------------------------------------- -- " << std::endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
};

#endif
```

this is the login.cpp file which binds to the login.ui GUI file.

```
#include "login.h"
#include "ui_login.h"

login::login(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
    , ui(new Ui::login)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

login::~login()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

this is the login.h header file

```
#ifndef LOGIN_H
#define LOGIN_H

#include <QtWidgets/QMainWindow>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui { class login; }
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class login : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    login(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~login();

private:
    Ui::login *ui;
};
#endif // LOGIN_H
```

trying to compile all of this turns out 212 errors like these (my project is called "simulador_7"):

```
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __cdecl QAbstractScrollArea::eventFilter(class QObject *,class QEvent *)" (?eventFilter@QAbstractScrollArea@@MEAA_NPEAVQObject@@PEAVQEvent@@@Z) simulador_7 C:\Users\Jose Miguel\Documents\simulador\simulador_7\simulador_7\simulador_7\login.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __cdecl QAbstractScrollArea::viewportEvent(class QEvent *)" (?viewportEvent@QAbstractScrollArea@@MEAA_NPEAVQEvent@@@Z)  simulador_7 C:\Users\Jose Miguel\Documents\simulador\simulador_7\simulador_7\simulador_7\login.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __cdecl QLabel::event(class QEvent *)" (?event@QLabel@@MEAA_NPEAVQEvent@@@Z)    simulador_7 C:\Users\Jose Miguel\Documents\simulador\simulador_7\simulador_7\simulador_7\login.obj  1   
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "protected: virtual bool __cdecl QLabel::focusNextPrevChild(bool)" (?focusNextPrevChild@QLabel@@MEAA_N_N@Z)  simulador_7 C:\Users\Jose Miguel\Documents\simulador\simulador_7\simulador_7\simulador_7\login.obj  1
```

I hope someone is able to see whats going on. I know such errors are because the compiler cannot find the "__cdecl" macro or reserved word, but I've googled about this keyword in specific and it doesn't seem to belong to any library or include folder in particular, so I am in the dark to whats going on. Sorry if I'm not making myself clear, I am new to C++. Feel free to ask for anything else that I might have not included.

Answer (score 1):

Just on a side note this is how you should be processing events rather that running a while loop.

It would be advisable to use the Qt Opengl rather than a mix of GLFW and QT.

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
login w;
w.show();

QTimer timer;
timer.setInterval(0);
timer.setSingleShot(true);

QObject::connect(&timer, &QTimer::timeout, [&]() {

if (glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0 ) {

  // do the rendering stuff
      glfwPollEvents();
      glfwSwapBuffers(window);
      timer.start();

}
else
{
    glfwTerminate();
    application.quit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It all came together when I included a path to qtwidgets inside the C/C++ additional include files options. It has to recognize the whole of qtwidgets so you can write "#include " without errors.